# Django отправляет два ответа на один и тот же запрос

Tags: python, django

Я отправляю HTTP-запрос. Далее программа пытается найти объект, которого не существует. Я, как и хотел, получаю код статуса `404`. Но потом программа присылает мне ещё один ответ (`200` или `500`, неважно).
То есть после того, как блок `except` отработал и инструкция `return HttpResponseNotFound` была выполнена, программа возвращается обратно и выполняет инструкцию `return render()`. Я думал, что после блока `except`, программа отправит ответ со статусом `404` и прекратит выполнение.

Мне кажется или я не всё знаю о `try: except:`?

```
try:
    self.object = ...
except ObjectDoesNotExist as exception:
    return HttpResponseNotFound(
            content=render_to_string(
            template_name='404.html',
            context=self.get_context_data(),
            request=request
        ))
return render(...)
```

Comment: ну так у вас return render вызывается вне блока try-except, другими словами, независимо от него.